# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute in a thread

Tags: c#, error-handling, enumeration

I really cannot get to the bottom of this error, its probably visible but need a extra pair of eyes!

```
try
{
    while (Program.Alive)
    {
        List<Session> ToDispose = new List<Session>();
        List<Session> ToStop = new List<Session>();

        lock (mSessions)
        {
            lock (mSessionsToStop)
            {
                foreach (uint SessionId in mSessionsToStop)
                {
                    if (mSessions.ContainsKey(SessionId))
                    {
                        ToStop.Add(mSessions[SessionId]);
                    }
                }

                mSessionsToStop.Clear();
            }

            foreach (Session Session in mSessions.Values)
            {
                if (ToStop.Contains(Session))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (Session.Stopped)
                {
                    if (Session.TimeStopped > 15)
                    {
                        ToDispose.Add(Session);
                    }

                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ToStop.Count > 0)
        {
            using (SqlDatabaseClient MySqlClient = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
            {
                foreach (Session SessionStop in ToStop)
                {
                    SessionStop.Stop(MySqlClient);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Session SessionDispose in ToDispose)
        {
            SessionDispose.Dispose();

            lock (mSessions)
            {
                if (mSessions.ContainsKey(SessionDispose.Id))
                {
                    mSessions.Remove(SessionDispose.Id);
                }
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(70);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Output.WriteLine("[ExecuteMonitor.Error] " + e.Message, OutputLevel.CriticalError);
}
```

It runs in a separate thread and we are always getting errors regarding Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Comment: which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: It does not say, at the bottom we catch the error and output it to the console and we only output the message, so all we are getting is...

[ExecuteMonitor.Error] Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Comment: @RichardWilliams: that's why to not just display ex.Message. Display `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: @RichardWilliams So change it to actually display the full stack trace instead of discarding valuable debugging information and then tell us.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any editing while enumerating in this code example.

Are you 100% certain you aren't forgetting to `lock` your non-local variables?

Editing `mSessions` or `mSessionsToStop` outside of a lock would cause the exception you describe.